# How do I look up a Clojure keyword in IPersistentMap from Java?

Tags: java, clojure

Calling a Clojure library from a Java program. I get an IPersistentMap back.

The keys are Clojure keywords like :name etc.

But it seems I can't just do a

```
map.valAt(":name");
```

to pull it out in Java. I'm guessing that's because the keys aren't normal java Strings. So what are they? And how can I pull data out of an IPersistentMap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using `Clojure.read` ? =>

`map.valAt(Clojure.read(":name"))`

or maybe =>

`// (:name my-map)
myMap.invoke(Clojure.read(":name"));`

Clojure 1.6 Java API
https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#21-java-api

Clojure's JavaDoc
https://clojure.github.io/clojure/javadoc/

Comment: Just trying to import clojure.java.api.Clojure; but don't seem to be able to find it. (clojure.lang is available. I assume it came as part of the uberjar lein made from my project. Do you know if clojure.java would get included when I package up a Clojure project that way? Or, if not, where is it?

Comment: @interstar What version of Clojure are you using?

Comment: @interstar I believe you have to either 1) Have the Clojure JAR available to your project 2) Rebuild the Uberjar but have your project's namespace require clojure.java.api.Clojure so that it's available to you.

Comment: the -standalone jar created by uberjar should contain clojure.java.api.Clojure (presuming you're using Clojure 1.6.0+).

Comment: OK. That solved it. Thanks @runexec + alex. (Needed to update to Clojure 1.6. It's still a bit clunky though. I now have a lot of Clojure.reads scattered all over my code.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to use the reader.  Clojure keywords are of type `clojure.lang.Keyword`.  You can create one using the static method `intern`:

`map.valAt(clojure.lang.Keyword.intern("name")); // Note: no leading colon`